# Segmentation Fault - C Language

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

I am writing a C program that reads a text file full of chars. It reads the text file and puts each char into a char array. (I later will be using vertex/edge pointers to accomplish other tasks). At this stage in the program I am just trying to print the char array of letters from the text file but I am getting a "Segmentation Fault"

To note, this program runs using jGrasp, but when using the same code in PICO I get this error.

There is when the error occurs:

```
edgetag* e = (edgetag*)malloc(sizeof(edgetag));   //SEGMENTATION FAULT SEEMS TO LIE HERE
```

Here is the majority of my program:

```
typedef struct edgetag{             //edge structure

   vertex* v;
   struct edgetag* q;

}edgetag;

      if(counter == 2){                                     //if counter == 2, make an edge

      int l = 0;
      while(l < 100){

         if(vertices[l].c == text[j]){                      //find what vertex needs the edge
         (*theVertex) = vertices[l];
         l = 100;

         }

         l++;

      }

     edgetag* e = (edgetag*)malloc(sizeof(edgetag));   //SEGMENTATION FAULT SEEMS TO LIE HERE (SIZEOF??)

      (*e).v = theVertex;                             //the edges vertex is equal to the last read vertex
      (*e).q = NULL;
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Check the value of `i` whille reading the file in order not to cause buffer overrun.

Comment: You may want to use `isupper((unsigned char)input[0])` instead of the too long condition. Cast is used to avoid passing negative values and causing undefined behavior.

Comment: Compile with all warnings & debug info (`gcc -Wall -Wextra -g`). Use the debugger `gdb` & `valgrind`

Answer (score 1):

MikeCat's comment is right, you should add a check of `i` inside the while loop.

Your segmentation fault is likely caused by the file being to big to be stored in a char[100]. char[100] means that there is no more than 100 characters in the file.

Something like that would probably fix your problem :

```
while(fgets(input, 2, file)){

    if(input[0] == 'A' || input[0] == 'B' || input[0] == 'C' || input[0] == 'D' || input[0] == 'E' || input[0] == 'F' || input[0] == 'G' || input[0] == 'H' || input[0] == 'I' || input[0] == 'J' || input[0] == 'K' ||
       input[0] == 'L' || input[0] == 'M' || input[0] == 'N' || input[0] == 'O' || input[0] == 'P' || input[0] == 'Q' || input[0] == 'R' || input[0] == 'S' || input[0] == 'T' || input[0] == 'U' || input[0] == 'V' ||
       input[0] == 'W' || input[0] == 'X' || input[0] == 'Y' || input[0] == 'Z'){
        if(i < 100){
            text[i] = input[0];
            i++;
        }else{
            // File is too big! Do something to handle the error
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I edited my original post for a more specific issue that I found with the segmentation error